# Retrieve Typescript class properties

Tags: typescript, reflection

If you have a class

```
export class Address {
  id: number;
  addrLine1: string;
  addrLine2: string;
  ...
}
```

After you create an object

```
const address = new Address();
```

You can skip TypeScript compiler by adding another property to `Address` class

```
address['addrLine3'] = 'some value';
```

I would like to only keep keys that are part of the class `Address` in the object (at a later time than instantiation).

Meaning, I would like to remove `addrLine3` key from the `address` object.

We could do it if we could list all fields of the class `Address` reflectively but that doesn't seem possible, or is it?

Or, could there be any other way?

One way would be to create one object of `Address` class with desired keys and compare against this object, but it's not the best way!

Comment: I don't think this would be possible. TypeScript's type info is erased from the compiled JavaScript output, so there's nothing left there from the way the class is declared to filter out extraneous properties at run time.

Comment: Yes what's what I came to know, but are there other ways of doing this, I updated my question with- _One way would be to create one singleton object of Address class and compare keys against this object_

Comment: Maybe lines can be an array of strings or some map ?
So you will be able to add/remove as more lines as needed. 
You can also add a method to convert address data to some needed format.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need reflection for this particular case - you just need a new clean address object, which won't have any naughty additional properties.

```
class Address {
  id: number = 0;
  addrLine1: string = '';
  addrLine2: string = '';
}

const addr1 = new Address();
addr1.addrLine1 = 'One';
addr1.addrLine2 = 'Two';
addr1['addrLine3'] = 'Line Three!';

function getCleanAddress(address: Address): Address {
    const cleanAddress = new Address();
    for (const prop in cleanAddress) {
        cleanAddress[prop] = address[prop];
    }
    return cleanAddress;
}

const addr2 = getCleanAddress(addr1);

// Object { id: 0, addrLine1: "One", addrLine2: "Two", addrLine3: "Line Three!" }
console.log(addr1);

// Object { id: 0, addrLine1: "One", addrLine2: "Two" }
console.log(addr2);
```

Caveat... you need to ensure all properties on an empty instance have a value, otherwise the TypeScript compiler will optimise them away.

Comment: Exactly @Fenton. Pls read last line of question _One way would be to create one singleton object of Address class and compare keys against this object_. **It's exactly what I meant!**

Comment: This isn't a singleton, it's an instance. What would you like - more options? How about keeping the desired keys in a "valid keys dictionary", or maybe a static method on Address that accepts any subclass of Address but manually maps only the desired fields.

Comment: Yes, wanted to discuss more ways of achieving this. Keeping valid keys in dictionary is one of the options similar to keeping the instance with all the clean keys (as above). 
Keeping the static method or sub class might not meet the use case as you would create instance of the target class only, even so is there a way to call that method reflectively based on the class name of instance (from `obj.constructor.name`) as it needs to be handled generically  at a 3rd place, e.g., service class

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of how to have dynamic number of lines using array,
but you may consider to store lines into map.

```
class AddressExample {

  constructor(
    private _id: number,
    private _lines: string[]
  ){

  }

  public addLine(line:string){
    this._lines.push(line);
  }

  public removeLastLine(){
    this._lines.pop();
  }

  public removeLine(index:number){
    this._lines.splice(index, 1);
  }

  public toNeededFormat(){
    let result = {
      id: this._id,
    };

    this._lines.forEach((line: string, index:number) => {
      result['addrLine'+index] = line;
    });

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: you didn't exactly understand the question, it's not only the address lines, but a generic way to remove extra keys from the object.